# Got a name for our stuff toy

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

We are like babies, we still love our stuff toys even if we are already grown up, and we have 1 specific stuff toy that has a name that doesn't really exist for us humans.

I have made a puzzle to figure out each bit of the 6-letter name, and you have to try and figure it out. Good luck.

1. We love lilacs lying on the windowsill while we look at the lamps in my lightning Lamborghini.
2. The popular name of awards for artistic and technical merit in the film industry.
3. A liquid in different types. Either sanitary or NSFW.
4. Elementary, Interpret, Emptiness, Expressway, Deer
5. It connects computers on the web.
6. Bow, Cave (in), Give in, Submit, Succumb, Surrender / Earnings, Gain(s), Income, Incoming(s), Proceeds, Profit, Return, Revenue

**H1:**

> All given letters aren't in order, the name is scrambled here. The beginning and last letters should be vowels.

**H2:**

> This is 2 hints in one.
>
>  1. The format of the name is 4 vowels and 2 letters: VCVCVV
>
>  2. [**@hexomino**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino) actually was close on getting Letter 3. Remove some words and leave the one that suits it.

**H3:**

> If we were to halve the name pattern, it would be VCV CVV. VCV is actually the letters of 3, 5 and 6, so I think you know what CVV is.

Comment: If I should give another hint, just let me know, or I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: I think it's rather unfair this puzzle required anagramming to a completely made-up word; it is impossible to guess without your "hints" (though I wouldn't consider necessary information hints) giving various positional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the hints and some prompting by the OP, I now think the answer is

> **IYALEO**

Part 1

> Given the prevalence of the letter **L** in the sentence, I guess that this line is cluing **L**

Part 2

> The answer is the Oscars, which clues the letter **O** (think Nato phonetic alphabet)

Part 3

> It seems the answer here is alcohol, which, I think, clues the letter **A** and can either be sanitary (used for treating cuts) or NSFW (because of its effect on the senses).
>  **Previous Guess** There are several alcoholic drinks under the name [XXXX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXXX_Bitter) so I'm guessing it clues **X**

Part 4

> Each word here contains the letter **E** twice, so I think this might be cluing **E**

Part 5

> The answer here is the internet so this must clue the letter **I**.

Part 6

> These words are all synonyms for the word **yield** so this must be cluing **Y**.

Putting this all together

> We have an anagram of either **LOAEIY** which must follow the pattern VCVCVV. We are also told in the hints that the last three letters come from clues 1,2,4 - thus **LEO**, and the remaining letters must either form **AYI** or **IYA**, the second of which seems more likely from an ease of pronunciation standpoint.
>  Overall, we obtain **IYALEO** as the stuffed toy's name.

Comment: The name could also be Bkl orpnhfr yvr vf n erq ureevat.

Comment: @JoeKerr I'm not sure, it does specifically say 6-letter name in the question.

Comment: oops. I guess my eye just skipped over that part of the question. Didn't see it when I posted the first comment.

Comment: Hello, @hexomino. You nearly got all letters and your guess is still wrong. I suggest you look back at the question since it now has 2 more hints, so that will help you. It can be on this answer or another one, one that might be community-wiki.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe One question I had was, do you count Y as a consonant or a vowel?

Comment: The real one is AYI, which I don't want to reveal the reasoning behind it. You finally got the answer, congrats.